# How to display small, modal view controller in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I am wondering how to display a small view controller that takes up a small portion of the overall height of the view in a modal fashion.

I have created a `TestViewController` class that contains a single `UIButton` that I care about pressing.  This view controller is displayed after a certain action is performed in a previous view controller, and only takes up a small % of the overall height.

So far I have this code, which achieves the goal of making the view controller "smaller" and occupying a specific size.

```
TestViewController *testViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-80.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 80.0);

testViewController.view.frame = frame;

[self addChildViewController:testViewController];
[self.view addSubview:testViewController.view];
[testViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

However how can I configure this view controller such that if I tap outside of the view controller I either get notified and can take an action (i.e. dismiss myself) or have the touches blocked entirely?  Is this possible?

I tried making the view controller fill the entire screen, and then have a transparent view used to "intercept" touches that occur outside of the small subview that would be used to display my content, but I couldn't get the `UIViewController` to be transparent, using a clear background resulted in a black background being displayed.

I am currently looking at the `modalPresentationStyle` property, but that doesn't seem to be helping so far.

Comment: I made a Github repo [BonsaiController](https://github.com/rishi420/Bonsai) just for that.

Answer (score 0):

For making `UIViewController` transparent you have to present `ModalViewController` and set property of `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`.

```
 ModalViewController *mvc = [[ModalViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ModalViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    
 mvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    
 [self presentViewController:mvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In `ModalViewController` you need to set `backgroundcolor` clear and set `opaque` false.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.view.opaque = false;
```

If you want to make transparent your `ModalViewController` then set `backgroundcolor` and opacity as per your requirement.

Comment: This works to make a fullscreen - now how do you combine that with the ability to take up only a portion of the screen, and listen for touches outside of the area I care about?